# How to replace the Standard Magento "Missing/No Image" Graphic

Tags: magento2, image, product-images

I want to globally use my own graphic image if my client does not upload a product photo. How can I best replace the standard Magento graphic with my own custom graphic?

Backend? CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload a placeholder image in the admin under Store> configuration > catalog > placeholder image (the name of this final option might be slightly different, not at my desk right now).

Comment: hank you @Weaves81. I like this answer. I'll try it and post back shortly.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Weaves81. Note: it is Stores > Configuration... and not System > Configuration

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)